# How to perform an action as long as a Button is kept pressed

Tags: android

Hi and Thanks for your help.

I need a button to perform the following behavior:

- when the button is pressed an action begins (in this case a view scrolls)
- as long as the button is kept pressed the action continues (the view continues scrolling)
- when the button is released the action (the scrolling) stops.

I have tried this, but does not work:

```
Button left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);


    left.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("","left");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 //Start your work
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
 // stop the work
        break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
 // stop the work
        break;
    }
    return false;
}



});
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However I am struggling to get onclick on the button also, any idea what should be done?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a combination of [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)

**Edit:**

```
    switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // TODO start scroll
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // TODO stop scroll
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` for detecting action up as well as down

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //start action here
            break;


        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default you can use onlongclick listener, But in your case it won't give effect as its max time 1-2 sec, so apply motion event on button and apply your logic..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` for detecting action up and down

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //start action
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //stop action
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

make new scroll view

```
ScrollView sv=new ScrollView(this);
```

and when you click/start button. then start thread which increment int value and scroll, and on key action down. stop the thread.

```
//start thread which incrment value one by one 
sv.scrollBy(x, y); //x  the amount of pixels to scroll by horizontally 
           //y  the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically
```